# How to convert every Table from a specific User to JSON Format using the "trick" provided by SQL Developer

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to convert all tables from a specific user to JSON (or XML) Format. I've read about a "trick" mentioned by SQL Developer.

In other words, I already started to create a Procedure with two parameters:

- p_format: The format (in my case it will be "json")
- p_user: The username

As IDE I use **Oracle SQL Developer** and my database is an **Oracle XE Database**.

At first the procedure loops though all tables of the given user and in the loop, it should execute the following:

```
SELECT /*p_format*/ * FROM p_user || '.' || table
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use this SELECT Statement as mentioned above. I need to use the command `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <Statement>`.

The next problem I faced was the following: I wanted to output the result of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. Therefore I used the command `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <Statement> INTO <Variable>`. After compiling the procedure and executing it, I stumpled across the following Error:

```
"inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

This is my code of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_TABLE_TO_FORMAT_FROM(p_format VARCHAR2, p_user VARCHAR2) IS
/***************************************************************************
        Author: 
        Class:  
        School: 
        Date:   

        Function - EXPORT_TABLE_TO_JSON_FROM(p_user):
        Displays the data of every table from a given User as JSON
        Parameter: p_user ... User
***************************************************************************/ 
v_tableData VARCHAR2(32767);
v_sqlStatement VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR tablerec IN (SELECT *
                   FROM   ALL_TABLES
                   WHERE OWNER = p_user)
  LOOP
    v_sqlStatement := 'SELECT /*' || p_format || '*/ * FROM ' || p_user || '.' || tablerec.TABLE_NAME;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sqlStatement INTO v_tableData;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_sqlStatement);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You can see that I loop though all tables of a given user and created a sql statement with `p_format` and `p_user` and with `tablerec.TABLE_NAME`.

The desired result should look exactly like that:

```
{"results":[{"columns":[{"name":"COUNTRY_ID","type":"CHAR"},
{"name":"COUNTRY_NAME","type":"VARCHAR2"},{"name":"REGION_ID","type":"NUMBER"}],"items":
[
{"country_id":"AR","country_name":"Argentina","region_id":2},
{"country_id":"AU","country_name":"Australia","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"BE","country_name":"Belgium","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"BR","country_name":"Brazil","region_id":2},
{"country_id":"CA","country_name":"Canada","region_id":2},
{"country_id":"CH","country_name":"Switzerland","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"CN","country_name":"China","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"DE","country_name":"Germany","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"DK","country_name":"Denmark","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"EG","country_name":"Egypt","region_id":4},
{"country_id":"FR","country_name":"France","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"IL","country_name":"Israel","region_id":4},
{"country_id":"IN","country_name":"India","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"IT","country_name":"Italy","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"JP","country_name":"Japan","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"KW","country_name":"Kuwait","region_id":4},
{"country_id":"ML","country_name":"Malaysia","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"MX","country_name":"Mexico","region_id":2},
{"country_id":"NG","country_name":"Nigeria","region_id":4},
{"country_id":"NL","country_name":"Netherlands","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"SG","country_name":"Singapore","region_id":3},
{"country_id":"UK","country_name":"United Kingdom","region_id":1},
{"country_id":"US","country_name":"United States of America","region_id":2},
{"country_id":"ZM","country_name":"Zambia","region_id":4},
{"country_id":"ZW","country_name":"Zimbabwe","region_id":4}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON hint is specific to SQL Developer and SQLcl, not the database directly.  So you need to run the entire thing within these tools.

Easiest way to do that is to have your script *write* a script that you can then run, eg

```
spool /tmp/get_all_json.sql
select 'select /*json*/ * from '||table_name||';' 
from user_tables;
spool off
@/tmp/get_all_json.sql
```